# Launcher activity reopens when it is put into background and restored to foreground by clicking launcher right after installation process

Tags: android

An issue is about that a launcher activity reopens when it is put into background and restored to foreground by clicking launcher. This problem occurs only after first run when a user installs an app and launch it from a play store or an android package installer.

Here are steps to reproduce the issue:

1. The user installs the app from the play store or android package installer;
2. After installation the user opens the new installed app by clicking “OPEN” inside the play store app or the android package installer;
3. Inside the app the user goes to another activity and put the whole app into background by pressing a home button;
4. The user restored the app from background by clicking the app icon and new launcher activity is created.

In a result there are 3 activities instead of 2. Back stack looks like this:

1. Launcher activity;
2. Some other activity which was started by user inside the app;
3. Launcher activity.

Next, when the app is removed from a recent apps` list and above steps are performed again then the app behaves exactly as expected. New back stack looks like this:

1. Launcher activity;
2. Some other activity which was started by user inside the app.

I created example app to demonstrate the issue:
[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTUSf.png)

Here is shown installation process and a first run from the android package installer:
[first run](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xm91srp5OFL4VjxoIr-kOAF-ZOcP69ub/view?usp=sharing)

The user starts a SecondActivity inside of the app and puts app into background. Next, the user want to restore the app back to foreground and it turns out that a FirstActivity was created again.

Here is a back stack after above steps:
[back stack after first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCXFS.png)

Now, lets run the app in standard way:
[normal run](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fe50_At2swR2Juk0zQtk8kFP0WUD9TYZ/view?usp=sharing)

Before this test the app was removed from recent apps` list. The user starts the SecondActivity inside of the app and puts it into background by pressing home button. Next, the user restores the app back to foreground and this time the user sees the SecondActivity. The app behaves as expected now.

Here is the back stack after above steps:
[back stack after normal run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnmzV.png)

The issue doesn’t refer only to my example app. It can be verified using any app from the play store. I did such test on a Netflix app which was installed from the play store (btw. the Netflix home screen isn’t visible due to security policy):
[netflix first run](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17L5Z_YYp5edgYVBIdyY7N_GbQ8r7NnZG/view?usp=sharing)

Here are steps:

1. Install the Netflix app;
2. Open it from the play store;
3. Click “HELP” button on a main screen (inside the Netflix app);
4. Put app into background;
5. Click app icon;

The user sees again the main screen instead of a help screen. The back stack looks like this:

1. Main screen;
2. Help screen;
3. Main screen.

It can be verified by pressing back button then the user will see each screen one by one. As we can see the Netflix app behaves identical as my example app.

Can someone explain to my why does it happen?